# Activating API using Angular JS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, api

I'm trying to get the weather information from this service and fill the html with the dynamic data using AngularJS library.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Riyadh,ksa&appid=a809c777d6813b6b0905a9a7bf1a8399

Am I supposed to put this link in a script tag ? If yes, how I can use it with AngularJS. It is my first time using api's and AngularJS and I watched a lot of tutorials but none of them were like this api link.

Comment: The idea is you receive your data from the api end point and show them in your application. These may vary on angular versions 1, 2 ,4. but you can read the api documentation http://openweathermap.org/current to see how you can get the data. Then you can find some sample on web that others did using angular to display open weather data. But you should be familiar with Angular hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a GET API, you could use `$http.get` to call your API

```
    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <div ng-app="weatherApp" ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
    <button ng-click="GetWeatherInfo()">Get weather data</button>
    Temperature: {{weatherdata.main.temp}}
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('weatherApp', []);
    app.controller('weatherCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.GetWeatherInfo= function(){
           $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
                      q=Riyadh,ksa&appid=a809c777d6813b6b0905a9a7bf1a8399")
            .then(function(response) {
              $scope.weatherdata= response.data;
           }); 
        }
    });
    </script>
```

This will call your API on clicking the get weather data button. Once the API call is successful, you can access it anywhere in you html view with the `$scope` variable.

If you need your API call to be dynamic then you can construct the API url string within the function according to your requirement. I suggest you read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: I was incorrectly using response instead of response.data- It's working for me now. I've updated the code. Can you try this?

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this

```
app.controller("testController", function($scope,testService){
            testService.getData ()
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.testData = response.data;
                    // handle valid reponse

                },
                function(error) {
                    //handel error
                });
        }
```

Always handle errors .

Also you should create a service

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('testService', function ($http) {

   this.getData = function () {
      var endpoint = "url/";
      return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url:  endpoint
      });
    };

}
```

For a detailed view take a look at [this](https://github.com/noman57/login) simple application

Comment: @R_95 look at my example .. This would help you to get a good idea .. hope this helps .. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also make service like this

```
$http.get(url)
.then(function(response) {
// Request completed successfully
}, function(x) {
// Request error
 });
```